# increasing array index in a function

Tags: c++, arrays

i'm willing to write a code to create an array with a changeable index(meaning having a static array in a function and adding values to it and then getting out of the loop and coming back again and adding another value to the end of it)
but my code doesn't compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
void arrarr(int);
int main()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        arrarr(i);
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
void arrarr(int y)
{
    static int x[y];
    x[y] = 5;
    cout << x[y];
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)` In c++ array indices start at `0`: `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)`

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use an std container?

Comment: std container??
what's that?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ doesn't support variable length array, you need to define constant size for the static array `x`. You can do something like:

```
void arrarr(int y)
{
    static int x[SOME_CONSTANT_SIZE]; //SOME_CONSTANT_SIZE known at compile time
    x[y] = 5;   //y < SOME_CONSTANT_SIZE
    cout << x[y];
}
```

And as @Bruno pointed out, array indices start from `0` to `(size-1)`

If you are looking to dynamically increase the size of your array, you cannot do that. Use a `vector` instead. See here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/

Comment: i just want to kind of erase the array but keep the data in it for the next loop how can i do that?

Comment: Yes, define array with a constant size, known at compile time. It will work like a normal static variable with values preserved through function call.

Comment: no i want to do something like if the user wanted to add another number, increase the index, if he didn't want to, print the array

Comment: You cannot increase the size of the array dynamically, use `vectors` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Variables can not have variable size. You have to define explicitly the size of the array `x`, for example: `static int x[5]`.

Also, arrays are zero-indexed, meaning the first element starts at 0. So your loop condition should be `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't compile because of this:

```
static int x[y];
```

The compiler doesn't know what `x` is, e.g.

```
int [0]
int [1]
int [2]
```

So you can do

```
void arrarr(int y) {
    static int x[10];
    x[y] = 5;
    cout << x[y];
}
```

but what you were doing won't work.

If you share what the expected output is, we might be able to help you more.

Comment: i just want to kind of erase the array but keep the data in it for the next loop how can i do that?